# Unable to connect DB on a remote server

Tags: linux, virtualbox, sqldeveloper

I have an OpenSUSE OS running under VirtualBox. I can connect to Oracle 11g database with SQLDeveloper from localhost, but when I try to connect it from another PC I have either

```
Io exception: Got minus one from a read call
```

or

```
Io exception: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

appearing in a random order.

Of course the system is available from everywhere within the local network and I can work with it via ssh, browse the website, etc.

Why does this error appear?